# No desktop, only background with the Unity plugin

Tags: unity, compiz

I tried all this stuff.

> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in. Install the
>   jibby you'll need to configure the settings by running this:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
> ```
>
> Then run it. The first part tells the terminal which display you want
>   it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
>
> ```
> export DISPLAY=:0
> ccsm
> ```
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes) to get back to
>   the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings
>   Manager screen sitting there.
>
> Find the Unity plugin. Enable it.
>
> Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have
>   to restart. You can do that by going back to TTY1 and running sudo
>   reboot.

But none of it worked. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, but nothing. I also have checked to make sure the Unity plugin is enabled.

Comment: Make sure your system is up-to-date: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: We need more information, such what graphics card/driver you are using and what version of Ubuntu you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which worked for me in Ubuntu 12.10:

Use Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal. Now use the following command in the terminal:

```
rm -rf .compiz-1
```

Source: [How To Fix: No Unity, No Launcher, No Dash In Ubuntu](http://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/)