# I accidentally deleted unity How do I reinstall it

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.10, windows-8, reinstall

I was on unity using the compiz config tool and I disabled unity. How do I get back? In unity I can't do control alt T or whatever the short cut for terminal is. I can't do those short cuts. I have gnome install but that does not work either. I have windows 8 on my grub boot loader too so If I need to boot into that I can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How enable Unity again?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450427/how-enable-unity-again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your title has the correct wording, here's how to get Unity back:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter TTY.
2. From here, login with your username and password.
3. Once the prompt appears, run `sudo apt-get install unity`.

If you only somehow disabled Unity, this should get it working again:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter TTY.
2. From here, login with your username and password.
3. Once the prompt appears, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop`.