# Setting up Ubuntu 16.04 with nvidia gtx 1070

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 16.04, lightdm

I have already opened a topic about this before, but I have tried some other things since.  I have recently purchased a computer with an nvidia 1070 graphics card. Ubuntu is having problems running this however.

I have tried following things:

**1.** After installing Ubuntu, an error occurred stating "out of range error". I solved by adding 'nomodeset' to the into grub config file. Reference Link: [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

The only difference was that I had to press 'esc' once while booting.

**2.** After this, on Desktop was not showing any of the icons, just the purple screen. From following guide and have worked through most of the solutions: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

**3.** After doing all this, I got stuck in login screen. As I try to login into the system and it never logged into system and comes back to the login screen again, Tried to solve as per given solution  in following link; installed lightdm and tried to reconfigure it: [14.04 unity does not start after login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634386/14-04-unity-does-not-start-after-login-screen)

Installation succeeded and when doing 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm' it. No screen pops up which lets me choose which one I want to use.

Anyway assuming it would all work fine, rebooted my computer and logged in (I didn't get stuck into a login screen), however the items didn't load *sigh*.

So it appears that I am kind of stuck in an error loop which I can't get out of.

Does anybody have any suggestions for this?

Riaan

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed the issue for now!

After some hours of research I noticed that I could do some basic stuff with my ubuntu terminal after logging in. I had the empty screen and could get basic options by right clicking the mouse.

So i figured, perhaps Unity is just not working properly.

In my case the following solved it:

[How enable Unity again?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450427/how-enable-unity-again)

I hope this helps others too!