# Ubuntu 22.04 Unity Desktop Environment "Oh no! Something has gone wrong!"

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, 22.04

Just installed Unity using "sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop --install-recommends" and when I logged in, I saw this message:

Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. All extensions has been disabled as a precaution.

I tried restarting, reinstalled ubuntu, but nothing worked.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I want Unity as my main desktop env. and I installed Unity using "sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop"

Comment: Dowloading the ISO of the Ubuntu Unity flavor and installing that may give you a better start in installing the Unity desktop.

Comment: seeing the same, and this approach had never been an issue before

Answer (score 12):

The error message I was able to find in `/var/log/syslog` suggested that it was unable to talk to the message bus. Initially, it would error as soon as I log in. Then after some miscellaneous tweaking, I was able to get it to run a bit on unity, but it would never stay for long or be responsive after logging in. gdm3 would always work though. When i would log into the lightdm greeter, I would press `ctrl+alt+t` to try to open the terminal. but, it wouldn't open. however, it would print in the logs that it was trying to open it, just timed out three times, and then compiz was turning off the unity shell because "it was impossible to delete" some file.

So, after googling a bit about the message bug, it seems that

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```

did the trick and i was able to get a stable unity session. afterwards i compared my `ccsm` settings and gnome-tweak-tool settings from my other pc and did things like resetting icons and window stylings and undoing keyconflicts in ccsm. Everything is back to normal as far as i can tell.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/450427/how-to-enable-unity-again - for after installing dbus-x11

Comment: Please check answer below and see if that might be easier.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - you mean to install gdm3? that is a non-answer to the original question.

Comment: So you mean that answer should be closed?

Answer (score 1):

If ur error is provocated by a black screen with only a cursor, and then install x11, then it can be "solved" by running a command:

```
sudo apt install gdm3
```

and setting GDM as default display manager, then rebooting

That works in my case

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem asked in the original question - the original poster was interested in running Unity as their desktop manager, not GDM3. Kind of a rude dismissal of the question, actually.\

Answer (score 1):

In my case I firstly get a blank screen, with just only a cursor in my screen, to solve I just only reinstall the unity desktop (sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-unity-desktop) with a ttyl session, no restart was needed for support you can join to telegram group:

https://t.me/ubuntuunitydiscuss/34246