# LightDM not loading any window managers

Tags: gnome, login, network-manager, lightdm, i3-wm

Short version:
LightDM doesn't quite load my i3 session correctly and fails splendidly at loading my vanilla Unity desktop session. I suspect it's a problem with LightDM's configuration or various startup files (e.g. .xinitrc, .profile, etc).

Now, when I hit the login manager and select i3 session as I log in, it shows a blank background. I have to load i3 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and running startx. When I do that, nm-applet no longer shows up in the lower right corner of my i3status bar as it did before. My bash shell also has a different font (it still highlights filenames, though). (Edit: htop is also suddenly not installed, which is really confusing.)

When I try to run a Unity session, I get a blank white text box taking up a small fraction of my screen that looks like it's supposed to be a terminal of some sort. I can't press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F(1-6)</kbd> and get back to a terminal, so I am forced to reboot. Fixing this problem isn't critical, but hopefully, it helps diagnose the problem.

Long version:

I installed i3 a while back.

```
sudo apt install i3
```

Upon my first reboot, I was initially very happy with it. I tweaked some nautilus settings to not show the desktop icons so I could use nautilus.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

After my second reboot, I logged in with my familiar Unity login manager and selected 'i3' as a session, I encountered a blank desktop background.

I followed the instructions [here:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279074/no-desktop-only-background-with-the-unity-plugin) to no avail, so I tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, resetting, and eventually removing my existing compiz configuration.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Here's my .xinitrc file, which I made at some point during this long process.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
VIMRUNTIME=/usr/bin
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim

# alias to allow quick vga connection
alias connect-vga='xrandr --output LVDS2 --auto --output VGA2 --preferred --right-of LVDS2'
alias disconnect-vga='xrandr --output LVDS2 --auto --output VGA2 --off'

# set primary display so that nm-applet icon shows up? untested
#xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary

# exec enlightenment_start
exec i3
```

P.S.: I also got a 4K monitor just about when all this happened. In fact, this started when I had some issues setting the resolution to something that would work with my 8-year-old Thinkpad T420. It seems to work fine now, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing, but you can try:

- make sure you check in LightDM startup screen Default Xsession
- there are two important config files: (1) `.xinitrc` and (2) `.xsession`
- to make sure everything is executed as expected, I have `.xinitrc` like this (just includes my `.xsession`) file:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # in some cases (?) the .xsession file was not processed
  # and so those commands needed to be manually executed here
  xrdb -merge ${HOME}/.Xresources
  . ${HOME}/.xsession
  ```
- everything important is in `.xsession`, there is bit more code over the years, but regarding the *i3*, the relevant parts contain:

  ```
  nm-applet &
  blueman-applet &
  pasystray &
  udiskie --smart-tray --file-manager="my-x-file-browser.sh" &
  clipit &
  shutter &
  dropbox start -i &
  exec i3 2>> ~/.xsession-errors
  ```

So as you can see, I start some applets and make sure the *stderr* of *i3* is redirected to a file, just to be sure I do not miss any error.

My advice:

1. LightDM has *Default Xsession* selected.
2. Make sure your `.xinitrc` gets executed (you may try the same setup as mine ie. use both `.xsession` as well as `.xinitrc`)
3. Redirect output to some log file (`2>> ~/.xsession-errors` can get quite big over time, so make sure to logrotate it or otherwise discard it)